# Reason for java.sql.SQLException "database in auto-commit mode"

Tags: java, sqlite, transactions

I use `sqlite` database and `java.sql` classes in servlet application to batch-insert some data into database.
There are consecutive four inserts of different kinds of data.
Each one looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn
    .prepareStatement("insert or ignore into nodes(name,jid,available,reachable,responsive) values(?,?,?,?,?);");
for (NodeInfo n : nodes)
{
    statement.setString(1, n.name);
    statement.setString(2, n.jid);
    statement.setBoolean(3, n.available);
    statement.setBoolean(4, n.reachable);
    statement.setBoolean(5, n.responsive);
    statement.addBatch();
}

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
statement.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
statement.close();
```

But sometimes I get the

```
java.sql.SQLException: database in auto-commit mode
```

I found in source code of `java.sql.Connection` that this exception is thrown when calling `commit()` while database is in autocommit mode. But I turn autocommit off before and I can't see any place for some parallel execution related issues as for now application is only turned on once.

Do you have any idea how to debug this issue? Maybe there's some other reason for this error (because I just found that exception about database not found or not well configured can be thrown when inserting `null` into non-null field)?.

Comment: Post code that shows what `methods` are used to prepare and execute `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thanks I edited the code to include statement preparation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be an issue *is* with *order* of statements. Your database statement should be :

```
  PreparedStatement statement1 = null;
  PreparedStatement statement2 = null;
  Connection connection=null;

    try {
        //1. Obtain connection and set `false` to autoCommit
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        //2. Prepare and execute statements
        statement1=connection.prepareStatement(sql1);
        statement2=connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
        ...
        //3. Execute the statements

        statement1.executeUpdate();
        statement2.executeUpdate();

        //4. Commit the changes

        connection.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        if (connection!=null) {
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {}
        }
    }finally {
        if (statement1 != null) {
            statement1.close();
        }
        if (statement2 != null) {
            statement2.close();
        }
       if(connection != null){
          connection.setAutoCommit(true);
          connection.close();
        }
   }
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said and wasn't able to reproduce the problem (the occurence of exception was a bit undeterministic), thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prepare your Statement and create the batch after `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`.

Answer (score 1):

When running this from a servlet, you have to make sure that the usage of the `Connection` is synchronized. Multiple requests could set the `Connection` to a different auto commit mode at nearly the same time. If you use one `Connection` per request, this will not be an issue. Otherwise, protect the above part with a critical section.

A tip regarding debugging which is applicable for tomcat / eclipse.

1) Enable JDPA debugging for your application server. In tomcat you can do this by adding the following lines to catalina.sh / catalina.bat:

```
 set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
 set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

2) Restart the application server

3) Connect with eclipse to your application server. "Debug as" --> "Remote Java Application"

4) Set a break point in above code.

5) Run the servlet.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation about the `Connection` and debugging. I will try to debug this way when I encounter other problems and also check how the `Connection` is used in our code.